# Remove from sale and auto update

Tags: ios, app-store

If I publish a new version to the app store and then remove from sale immediately, will this prevent auto updates for existing users? (which is what I want)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will prevent auto updates.

You can read more about this here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Regards